# How to create a hoverable drop down menu without consuming the space below it?

Tags: css

Since `display: block` does not work with transition, i just found some solutions here like using both opacity and visibility and animating opacity from 0 to 1, but this way takes up the space under the menu.

This is the code:

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;  
    visibility: none; 
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s linear;
}
```

**How to modify this code to save up the space under the menu while no submenu is active???**

**I would prefer one with `display:block;` if possible!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually almost there. `visibility: none` should be `visibility: hidden`. This makes the element unclickable and unhoverable... until you hover over the parent `.menu` element.

Demo:

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: powderblue; /* colors for clarity */
}

.menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    opacity: 0;
    background: lightskyblue;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear; /* good practice to put this here */
}

.menu:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div>Hover Over Me</div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Some content that isn't supposed to move</p>
```

As a further note on your intro, you cannot animate `display:block`, but you absolutely could switch the property value for the `:hover` pseudo-class:

```
.sub-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

.menu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**However...** your transition fade-in won't work anymore if you do that. Switching `visibility` is a better choice when you want to use a transition.

Either way won't insert any space beneath the menu (your code was already accomplishing that with `position:absolute`).

### Update:

Since your comment said you need to use `display: none` on the hidden menu, you can use the display switch and change opacity with an `animation` property instead of `transition`.

```
.menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute; 
    display: none; 
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    animation: reveal 0.4s linear;
    opacity: 1;
    /* be sure declare the final opacity like this, or else it'll revert to 0 after the animation completes */
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

You can drop the `visibility` property entirely, since it's not doing anything here.

Comment: thanks but this does not solve the problem, ```display: none``` differs from ```visibility:hidden``` in that the first hide the element from the dom totally, while the second keep it in the dom, i want to take advantage of hiding submenu from the dom while the submenu is hidden, this is my question!!

Comment: and for your notice, yes this was the first thing to do to switch display when hover but i need to make a transition so it is useless

Comment: If you must use `display: none` for DOM removal, then your best bet is to use the `animation` property instead of `transition`. It's more verbose, but it'll work (unless you need to support IE <10). I'll edit my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

What about using transform to have it slide in from the top? This way it never covers your content.

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index:666;
}

.main-menu{
    /* just some styles so you cannot see the dropdown transition behind it */
    padding:1.5em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;  
    top:6em; /* the height of the main-menu */ 
    left:0; right:0;
    z-index:-1;
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transform:translateY(-300%);
    /* aesthetic styles */
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    padding:1.5em;
    text-align:center;
}

.main-menu:hover + .sub-menu {
   transform:translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="main-menu">
    <p>Hover Me</p>
  </div><!-- main menu -->
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <p>Submenu</p>
  </div><!-- sub-menu-->
</div><!-- menu -->
```

Comment: no, actually it is an example of how transform:translateY works. If it does not work for you then you'll have to be more specific as to WHY it is useless. I have used this transform method hundreds of times on projects and it works just fine.

Comment: No, the example is almost perfect, just, I'd set the `:hover` state on the `.menu` class to make it preservable (even on submenu mouseenter) - otherwise the submenu has no use in this state (you cannot hover submenu items) ;) Happy coding!

Comment: this is a good option, but this does not fit what i really want to do, i need to show the submenu below the menu just as if display block can be animated(opacity increase gradually), unfortunately it can not be, so i need an alternative to have the same effect!!